# Not able to expire/remove cookie from browser using jquery

Tags: javascript, cookies, document

I am trying to expire/delete cookie with a specific name, although i am able to delete some cookie with name like "52847" or name with any number but not able to delete all the cookie like with name "_gid", "pardot", "personalization_id".

Here is what I tried -

```
document.cookie = "_gid=; value=; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

I also check whether this could be due to the *Path* that I used along with the cookie. But the path is correct.
See below image - 
[Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v87XG.png)

What could go wrong? Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to take off the attribute path if you're using the default path, tested it localy and it seems to work without